# How to convert three lists x,y,z into a matrix z[x,y]?

Tags: python, numpy

Given three lists `x,y,z` of identical size à la

```
x = [1, 0,.2,.2, 1, 0]
y = [0, 0, 0, 1,.2,.2]
z = [0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]
```

with unique but incomplete pairings of `x,y` float values, how to map `z` to a matrix `Z[i,j]` where `i,j` correspond to the indices `np.unique` of `x,y` respectively? In the example this would be something like

```
Z = [[ 2,  0,  3],
     ['', '',  1],
     [ 1,  0, '']]
```

where `''` might as well be `np.nan`. This does somehow sound like an inverse `np.meshgrid`, and I could hack up my own implementation, but is there no pre-existing solution?

I tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33942700/321973), but they assume a complete grid. [Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33948499/321973) sounds nice but interpolates the missing points, which is not what I want.

Comment: First, rename Z to R (otherwise you have two z variables). Then Initialize `R` as a matrix of `Nan`, then loop through `x` and assign the `z[i]` value to the `R[x[i],y[i]]` coordinate

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thanks, that's about what I would have done. But fortunately Divakar knows [a simpler way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42923907/321973)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be -

```
m,n = np.max(x)+1, np.max(y)+1    
out = np.full((m,n), np.nan)
out[x,y] = z
```

Sample run -

```
In [213]: x = [4,0,2,2,1,0]
     ...: y = [0,0,0,1,2,5]
     ...: z = [0,2,3,1,0,1]
     ...: 

In [214]: m,n = np.max(x)+1, np.max(y)+1    
     ...: out = np.full((m,n), np.nan)
     ...: out[x,y] = z
     ...: 

In [215]: out
Out[215]: 
array([[  2.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  3.,   1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

For floating point values, we could use `np.unique(..return_inverse)` to give each of the X's and Y's unique int IDs, which could be used as row and column indices for indexing into output array -

```
x_arr = np.unique(x, return_inverse=1)[1]
y_arr = np.unique(y, return_inverse=1)[1]

m,n = np.max(x_arr)+1, np.max(y_arr)+1    
out = np.full((m,n), np.nan)
out[x_arr,y_arr] = z
```

Sample run -

```
In [259]: x = [1, 0,.2,.2, 1, 0]
     ...: y = [0, 0, 0, 1,.2,.2]
     ...: z = [0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]
     ...: 

In [260]: x_arr = np.unique(x, return_inverse=1)[1]
     ...: y_arr = np.unique(y, return_inverse=1)[1]
     ...: 
     ...: m,n = np.max(x_arr)+1, np.max(y_arr)+1    
     ...: out = np.full((m,n), np.nan)
     ...: out[x_arr,y_arr] = z
     ...: 

In [261]: out
Out[261]: 
array([[  2.,   1.,  nan],
       [  3.,  nan,   1.],
       [  0.,   0.,  nan]])
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know indexing in numpy can do that :) **edit** Ok, small catch, this only works for integer `x,y`s...

Comment: Sorry, I should not have used `0,1,2` as example values when they might as well be arbitrary floats... Still, this is a good starting hint, I'll think about it some more

Comment: OK, for floats, replace `out[x,y]` by `out[xi,yi]` where `xi = np.asarray([np.arange(len(ux))[ux==v] for v in x]).flatten()` with `ux = np.unique(x)` and same for `yi`. Though I guess my construct can be optimized...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Added a modified one for  floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42923907/321973), but also working for non-index `x,y`s:

```
ux, xi = np.unique(x, return_inverse=1)
uy, yi = np.unique(y, return_inverse=1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(ux, uy)
Z = np.full(X.shape, np.nan)
Z[xi, yi] = z
```